# Extract certain column from CSV files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, grep, csv

I have a directory with a group of CSV files. All files have the same column headers. I need to extract values in a certain column from all files.

The common part in files names is `OCS_mobfwref-oam_d01_2014080*`

Comment: Provide a sample of the data in the files, to see what the delimiter is, the number of columns, etc...  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Next time, please give us an example of your input and the output you want. It makes it much easier to understand what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract from the 3rd column for example, you can do:

```
cut -d',' -f3 OCS_mobfwref-oam_d01_2014080*
```

This only works if there are no un-escaped comma's!

If you want to remove the headers, do:

```
sed 1d OCS_mobfwref-oam_d01_2014080* | OCS_mobfwref-oam_d01_2014080*
```

Comment: removing headers isn't working

Answer (score 2):

the same in awk, with a head in first 2 lines, extracting the third field, assuming filed separator is ',' (comma).

```
 awk -F, 'NR>2 { print $3 ; }' *.csv
```